# Import JavaScript file and call functions using webpack, ES6, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Trying to do something I would think would be very simple. I would like to import an existing JavaScript library and then call it's functions.  So for example I would like to import blah.js and then call blah().

```
import React from 'react';
import {blah} from 'blah/js/blah.js';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    }

    handleResize() {
        blah.blah();
    }

    render() {
          ....
    }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Just wondering what magical combination of things I have to do to make this work.  Maybe I'm just missing the point.  The example gives the error "TypeError: _blah.blah is undefined".

Comment: Without an example of the file you're trying to import, this is unanswerable. There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, but whether it works would depend on what is exported from `blah.js`.

Comment: Check in `blah.js` if you have named export of `blah` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 198, accepted):

**Named exports:**

Let's say you create a file called `utils.js`, with utility functions that you want to make available for other modules (e.g. a React component). Then you would make each function a *named export*:

```
export function add(x, y) {
  return x + y
}

export function mutiply(x, y) {
  return x * y
}
```

Assuming that utils.js is located in the same directory as your React component, you can use its exports like this:

```
import { add, multiply } from './utils.js';
...
add(2, 3) // Can be called wherever in your component, and would return 5.
```

Or if you prefer, place the entire module's contents under a common namespace:

```
import * as utils from './utils.js'; 
...
utils.multiply(2,3)
```

**Default exports:**

If you on the other hand have a module that only does one thing (could be a React class, a normal function, a constant, or anything else) and want to make that thing available to others, you can use a **default export**. Let's say we have a file `log.js`, with only one function that logs out whatever argument it's called with:

```
export default function log(message) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

This can now be used like this:

```
import log from './log.js';
...
log('test') // Would print 'test' in the console.
```

You don't have to call it `log` when you import it, you could actually call it whatever you want:

```
import logToConsole from './log.js';
...
logToConsole('test') // Would also print 'test' in the console.
```

**Combined:**

A module can have both a default export (max 1), and named exports (imported either one by one, or using `*` with an alias). React actually has this, consider:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

Comment: Makes sense but now I get errors like this:

SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: Then you're probably exporting stuff inside other blocks. As the error reads, you need to do it in the top-level (i.e. outside any blocks).

Comment: How can I import only util and call functions like util.add(), util.multiply() ?

Comment: @jiawen You can do: `import * as util from './utils.js'; `  (I added this to the answer as well).

Comment: `import * as utils from './utils.js';` worked best for me

Comment: There was a typo in the function name so we see a syntax error in export we need to change function multiply(x, y) to -> function multiply(x, y)

Answer (score 8):

```
import * as utils from './utils.js';
```

If you do the above, you will be able to use functions in utils.js as

```
utils.someFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the working code here :

Link to the Netlify React App using Javascript :
https://paint0183.netlify.app/

Source Code of Microsoft Paint Clone:
[Github Source Code](https://github.com/aditya-ahlawat-1309/MSPaint)

```
Faced the same problem but the answer was simple
```

why not import directly?

```
import {file-name} from "./file-path";

For example :
    import {jscolor} from "./jscolor";
```

The only thing which you need to add to make sure the javascript loads after the DOM has loaded :

```
window.onload=function() {

// your entire javascript code here 

}
```