# VueJS accessing externaly imported method in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, export, vue-component

I have an External Java Script File
**something.js**

```
function myFun(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World!";
  }

export default myFun;
```

and this is my vue component
**Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" name="button" @click="">Call External JS</button>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import something from "./something.js"
export default {

created(){
}
}
</script>
```

I have two questions.

1. First how do I call this method inside the created life cycle hook to automatically run.
2. Second how do I call this method by hitting the button "Call External JS"

Of-cause I know to change the content of a div can easily done by vueJS without the help of pure JS external files. But I'm asking this question for clarify the concepts of how do I use external JS files inside the vue component.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import JavaScript file and call functions using webpack, ES6, ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467574/import-javascript-file-and-call-functions-using-webpack-es6-reactjs)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. You can call the imported `something` function under any lifecycle method you want. Here, I'd recommend using the `mounted` method. That triggers once all of the component's HTML has rendered.
2. You can add the `something` function under the vue component's methods, then call the function directly from the template.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" name="button" @click="something">
            Call External JS
        </button>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import something from "./something.js"

export default {
    mounted() {
        something()
    },
    methods: {
        something,
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 23):

A better solution would be to to use mixins:

```
import something from './something.js'
export default {
  mixins: [something]
}
```

now you can use whatever methods / computed you have exported in `something.js`, directly on `this`.

So, in your example, you have `myFun()` exported from `something.js`, and we can call it from `Dashboard.vue` like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" name="button" @click="myFun">Call External JS</button>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import something from "./something.js"
    export default {
        mixins: [something],
        mounted(){
            this.myFun()
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope I got the syntax right, but that's generally the idea of mixins.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach would be to add the method in the data-block:

```
import something from "./something.js" // assuming something is a function

data() {
  return {
    // some data...
    something,
  }
}
```

Then in your template use it like:

```
<template>
    <div class="btn btn-primary" @click="something">Do something</div>
</template>
```

Comment: This solution is useful if you need to update the state of the object you are injecting

Comment: Nice solution! More clean and generic!

Answer (score 4):

With your example, external javascript file **something.js**

```
function myFun(){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World!";
}

export default myFun;
```

You can parse it like object in your methods:{} in **Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" name="button" @click="something">Call External JS</button>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import something from "./something.js"
export default {

   methods: {
      something,
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if in case of two separated files to include in methods? Like something1.js and something2.js

following doesn't works:
<script>
import something1 from "./something1.js"
import something2 from "./something2.js"
export default {

   methods: {
      something1, something2
   }
}
</script>

Comment: @user2543127 it should work, if your something1.js and something2.js are each export a method/function respectively

PS: you need to make sure variable something1, something2, is holding a function.

Comment: i tried but it doesn't worked.. Can you please provide me an example?
Thanks

Comment: @user2543127 Kindly find the following repo for the example. https://github.com/LarryMckuydee/vue-export-example

Answer (score 1):

The methods which are reactive or coupled with the components(which are not API's) should be written in `methods`.I follow this practice.
I have a scenario here to clarify your concepts:

JS file(one with containing function)filename - **apis.js**

```
export function GetApiCall(apiName, data, header) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do something here
  });
 }
```

I have used that function here in `created` hook.
Thing is you can use it one of the user-defined methods.

Vue file(one which we will use that function from js file) - filename - **infoform.vue**

```
 import { GetApiCall } from '../utils/apisget';
  export default{
    created(){
        // Invoked API to get Data of organization
        GetApiCall(URL,{},{
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token
            })
            .then(responseJson => {
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                this.$toasted.show(err);
                // console.log('error==',err);
            });
    },
  methods: {
     onClickMethod () {
       GetApiCall(URL,{},{});
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. =)

Answer (score 0):

I have created  `"/helpers/modalHelpermodalHelper.js".`

```
export default function modalHelper() {
   function showModalWithoutBackdrop(modalID) {
      $('#' + modalID).modal({
         backdrop: 'static',
         keyboard: false
      });
   }

   function showModal(modalID) {
      $('#' + modalID).modal("show");
   }

   function hideModal(modalID) {
      $('#' + modalID).modal("hide");
   }

   return {
      showModalWithoutBackdrop,
      showModal,
      hideModal,
   }
}
```

**Usage:**
In the vue component script part:

```
<script>
    
    import modalHelper from "@/helpers/modalHelpermodalHelper.js"
    
    const {showModal} = modalHelper();
    
    export default {
      methods: {
          showModal,
      }
    }
<script>
```

Now I'm able to use this method in the template.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to use this function in template without creating a new separate method that will call them.

```js
import { sumTwoNumbers, multiplyTwoNumbers }  from ‘../utils’;
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    // Add them here like this and they will be accessible in the template.
    sumTwoNumbers,
    multiplyTwoNumbers,
  }
}
```