# Vue.js: Import class with function and call it in child component

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, properties, vue-component

I have a component `my-parent`. In this component, I use a child component `my-child` and import an external class `MyClass` with an own function `exportedFunction`. I tried to use this solution: [VueJS accessing externaly imported method in vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144933/vuejs-accessing-externaly-imported-method-in-vue-component)

Basiclly, I use `mounted` and the name of the function from the imported class. In `methods` I defined a new method, which calls the mounted one from the imported class. Than I pass the created method as property to my child, where I try to call the function with a `@click` and pass the parameter there.

Here is my code so far:

`my-parent` template:

```
<template>
    <my-child :exportedFunction="callFunction"></my-child>
</template>

<script>
import MyClass from './MyClass';

export default {
    mounted() {
        exportedFunction()
    },
    methods: {
        callFunction() {
            exportedFunction()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

`my-child` template:

```
<template>
    <button @click="exportedFunction('hello world!')">Click me!</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['exportedFunction']
}
</script>
```

`MyClass` code:

```
export default class MyClass {
    exportedClass(parameter) {
        console.log(parameter) // expected 'hello world' from child
    }
}
```

Hope for some help!

Comment: Is there any reason why in the child component you don't emit an event for which you listen in your parent component and trigger the method there?

Comment: @Manu Since I'm really a newbie with Vue.Js didn't know, that there is such a way. How could I do it in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ditch your `MyClass` component and instead have:

`my-parent`

```
<template>
    <my-child :triggerEvent="callFunction"></my-child>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        callFunction() {
          console.log('hello');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

`my-child`

```
<template>
    <button @click="$emit('triggerEvent')">Click me!</button>
</template>
```

As you want to use `MyClass` in your example you can keep it as is and have `my-parent` as:

```
<template>
  <my-child :triggerEvent="callFunction"/>
</template>

<script>
import MyChild from "./MyChild";
import MyClass from "./MyClass.js";

export default {
  components: {
    MyChild
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myCls: new MyClass()
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myCls.exportedClass("hello my class");
  },
  methods: {
    callFunction() {
      console.log("hello");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Also, make sure you import your ```my-child``` component in your ```my-parent``` component

Comment: Thx! But I have to use the `MyClass` with the function. So can I call the function in `MyClass` from the parent component? So I would `emit` the call from the child and call the function in `MyClass` from the parent componet? Would this be possible?

Comment: Do you plan on reusing ```MyClass```? If so, we can use a mixin. Just curious to find out what the use of that will be.

Comment: @MrBuggy, I've updated my answer to make use of ```MyClass```. It would be good to understand the reasoning behind it as you may want to use a mixin - for best practices.

Comment: Thx! The reason is, it is an external class, which offers me a function to do some stuff. That's why I can not modify it or copy it out.

Comment: @MrBuggy, alright, makes sense, the above should work for what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it tomorrow and mark the answer as correct, if it works! Just to say it again: The Class is not written by me or within my code, it's something like a helper class, which is written by someone else and offers a function to do stuff for a specific requirement. So it would not make much sense, to modify this code or copy it out or what else. If so, I would not need this Class/Function written as helper class. Cheers