# Call function from imported helper class in Vue.js component data

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to call a `JavaScript` `function` from an imported helper `class` in my `Vue.js` `component`. I `import` my helper `class` in my `component` and try to use `mounted()` to call it and pass a paramter to the helper `class`.

I tried out some solutions from here, but didn't help:
[Vue.js: Import class with function and call it in child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293415/vue-js-import-class-with-function-and-call-it-in-child-component)

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-helper-functions-for-imported-modules-in-vuejs-vue-template/6266

This is what I tried so far, any ideas?

I have a helper class `myHelper.js`:

```
export default myHelper {
    myHelperFunction(param) {
        return param;
    }
}
```

I have a `Vue` component `MyComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field :rules="[myRule]"></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
import myHelper from './myHelper.js';

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      myCls: new myHelper(),
      myRule: this.callHelperFunction,
    };
  },
  components: {
    myHelper,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myCls.myHelperFunction();
  },
  methods: {
    callHelperFunction(param) {
      this.myCls.myHelperFunction(param);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really exporting the class. It is a plain object. To export a class instead of an object do this:

```
// Notice the use of class keyword
export default class MyHelper {
    myHelperFunction(param) {
        return param;
    }
}
```

Also, you do not need:

```
components: {
    myHelper,
},
```

Rest of the code stays the same.