# In the template, how to use a function that is imported?

Tags: vue.js

From an external file called `utils.js` I export a function called `todayYyyyMmDd`:

```
export const todayYyyyMmDd = () => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}).format(Date.now()).split('/').reverse().join('-');
```

Then in my component I import this function thus: `import { todayYyyyMmDd } from '@/utils';`

I want to use `todayYyyyMmDd` directly in my component's template like so:

```
<date-input
  :max="todayYyyyMmDd"
/>
```

Doesn't work. Instead I have to use an intermediary computed property:

```
today () {
  return todayYyyyMmDd();
},
```

Works, but it's ugly. Any way to use the imported function directly in template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS accessing externaly imported method in vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144933/vuejs-accessing-externaly-imported-method-in-vue-component)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whatever you import is not part of the vue instance. If you want to import a method and make it available for template, you need to have it in methods. Similarly, for an object, it has to be a data property.
Just using following would work as well:

```
methods: { todayYyyyMmDd }
```

which is shorthand for `todayYyyyMmDd: todayYyyyMmDd`