# Creating a module in react that will generate an array of 100 users

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Create a separate module getUsers.js that generates an array of 100 users:

- {id: 1, name: 'User 1'}
- {id: 2, name: 'User 2'}
- ....

I'm genuinely curious about how I could achieve something such as this using Javascript.  I know I could possibly create a loop.  I'm just unsure of how to create an array of objects in which the key-value pairs are also incrementing.  Any advice would be extremely helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string templating. If you want to import this from React, you need to export it from a file.

```js
// src/getUsers.js
function getUsers(n) {
  const users = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    users.push({ id: i, name: `User ${i}` });
  }
  return users;
}

export {
  getUsers
};
```

```js
// src/MyComponent.js
import { getUsers } from './getUsers';
function MyComponent(props) {
  const users = getUsers();

  return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: This works perfect, but If I wanted to create a module in react, which I would be fetching from, how would I do so.

Comment: see edit. also that has been asked a bunch on this site so check out e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467574/import-javascript-file-and-call-functions-using-webpack-es6-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#:%7E:text=Description-,Array.,such%20as%20Map%20and%20Set%20)

```js
function user(index) {
  return {
    id: index,
    user: `User ${index}`
  }
}

function generateUsers(length) {
  return Array.from({
    length
  }, (_, index) => user(index+1));
}

console.log(generateUsers(5))
```