# How do I load and run external Javascript code in React that have their definitions in the application and not in the imported file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Basically, I'm trying to run a function that creates and adds a Recipe class to an array in React based on an external javascript file that is hosted online - but all the definitions are inside my React app.

The external file looks like (Recipes.js) this:

```
function LoadRecipes(){
   
   AddToRecipes(new Recipe({
    name: "Kronyxium Core",
    components: [],
    requirements: [],
    craftedAt: "Frost Temple Smithy"
  }));
   
}
```

The way I attempt to go on with this follows:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import RecipeManager from "../logic/RecipeManager.js";
  const Recipe = RecipeManager.Recipe;
  const recipesList = RecipeManager.recipesList;
  const AddToRecipes = RecipeManager.AddToRecipes;

function RecipeController() {

  const [loadingRecipes, setLoadingRecipes] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://raw.githack.com/Soralei/extern/main/Recipes.js";
    script.async = true;

    script.onload = () => {
      setLoadingRecipes(false);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(script);

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!loadingRecipes){
      window.LoadRecipes();
    }
  }, [loadingRecipes]);

  return (
      <div>
        {loadingRecipes ? <p>Loading recipes...</p> : (
          <>
            <p>Recipes:</p>
            {/*recipesList.map((a, index) => <p key={"r"+index}>{a.name}</p>)*/}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
  )
}

export default RecipeController
```

Note that I try to run the function using window.LoadRecipes() once the script has been imported. However, I get undefined errors when the function is run:

```
Recipes.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: AddToRecipes is not defined
    at LoadRecipes (Recipes.js:3)
```

I'm also adding the content of RecipeManager.js for clarity. This is local logic, and the goal is to have the external function make use of it:

```
class Recipe{
    constructor(options = {}){
        this.name = options.name || "Unnamed Recipe";
        this.components = options.components || [];
        this.requirements = options.requirements || [];
        this.craftedAt = options.craftedAt || "handcrafted";
    }
}

const recipesList = [];

function AddToRecipes(Recipe){
    recipesList.push(Recipe);
    console.log(Recipe.name, "was added to the recipes list.");
}

const exported = {
    Recipe: Recipe,
    recipesList: recipesList,
    AddToRecipes: AddToRecipes
}

export default exported;
```

Is this not possible, or am I just doing this entirely wrong?

Why am I doing this? The idea is to host the recipes online in a way that allows for other people to easily view, edit, and have the changes affect my app directly, while keeping most of the work in the React app.

Comment: If you trying to simulate hosting you should fetch it

Comment: Do you have any examples on how this could be done? I have used fetch to read json files before, but I'm not sure how I am meant to fetch javascript and run a function etc.

Comment: `"../logic/RecipeManager.js"` this file, is this just plain JS and not ReactJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JavaScript file and call functions using webpack, ES6, ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467574/import-javascript-file-and-call-functions-using-webpack-es6-reactjs)

Comment: It's plain javascript that is then exported. I'll edit the original post to include the files content.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, unfortunately, no. The thread talks about importing local javascript files. I have to import my file differently, using 'document.createElement("script")' from what I know.

Comment: This is local, right?  `import RecipeManager from "../logic/RecipeManager.js";`?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the function to be able to access it.

Default export (only one per file):

```js
function LoadRecipes(){
   AddToRecipes(new Recipe({
    name: "Kronyxium Core",
    components: [],
    requirements: [],
    craftedAt: "Frost Temple Smithy"
  }));
}

export default LoadRecipes; // export
```

You should import it like this:

```js
import LoadRecipes from 'pathtofile';
```

Named export (multiple ones):

```js
export function LoadRecipes() {
  AddToRecipes(new Recipe({
    name: "Kronyxium Core",
    components: [],
    requirements: [],
    craftedAt: "Frost Temple Smithy"
  }));
}

export const add (a, b) => a + b; // another one
```

Import like this (using { }):

```js
import {
  LoadRecipes,
  add
} from 'pathtofile';
```

> Named exports are useful to export several values. During the import, one will be able to use the same name to refer to the corresponding value. Concerning the default export, there is only a single default export per module. A default export can be a function, a class, an object or anything else. This value is to be considered as the “main” exported value since it will be the simplest to import.

You can read about JavaScript modules [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to. 'Import' is used to import local files as far as I understand, and the script that I am loading is hosted externally on Github.


I can actually run things that I import when I do it the old way, so the import seems to work fine. The problem is just when I try to run things that are not defined in the imported file (but defined in my React app).

Comment: You are importing it from here right? `"../logic/RecipeManager.js"`

Comment: That's the locally hosted logic that defines the Recipe class, and the AddToRecipe function (which adds the class to an array). The external javascript function should then run this local logic. Since I'm importing this external file, I thought it would essentially become local as well and be able to make use of the local logic, but it seems like I get the mentioned error when I try.

Comment: Its probably a good idea to just copy the file into a file in your project and export / import the way I showed you, otherwise you would have to fetch this data and work asynchronously and you would depend on the external file. You can see this as a library, you would also `npm install` these to get the files into your own project. Using a cdn would also be possible but I wouldn't make things complicated.

Comment: I want people to be able to have easy access to viewing/editing the external file (i.e. straight on Github) and have the changes affect my app directly. So, I basically want my app to depend on the external file. Or, do you know of a better and more easy way to do this?

Comment: Letting other people change code that is hosted somewhere sounds like a dangerous thing to do, what is your goal exactly? If you want to let other people contribute to your project, you could just ask them to contribute to your github repo. This way you can check the code out before running any of it

Comment: That is the plan. That they can contribute to the repo. Not immediately edit the file, but my application then reads from the committed file.

Comment: Then the best thing to do is probably wait until someone commits to the repo, then review the code and merge it if you want to, then pull the code into your own project