# Trying to remove Token from local storage on "Logout" button

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, token

I'm creating a basic login form that stores token with whatever credentials are entered. In my `useToken.js` I've created an arrow function that should remove Token:

```
const removeToken = (userToken) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setToken(null);
};
```

In my header I got Logout button that should `removeToken` and logout user when it's clicked. My `Header.js` button that should Logout an user looks like this:

```
<Button variant="danger" onClick={removeToken}>
      LogOut
</Button>
```

It throws the `removeToken` is not defined error.

Comment: the removeToken should be in the same file, or should be imported correctly. Also, you don't need to pass userToken inside the removeToken method as it does nothing there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JavaScript file and call functions using webpack, ES6, ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467574/import-javascript-file-and-call-functions-using-webpack-es6-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Check this out (:

Answer (score 0):

Based on throwed the definition error, it seems that you haven't import function `removeToken` to the module where you are trying to use. So export it first then import it and then use.

The code with fix could look like that

**useToken.js**

```
export const removeToken = (userToken) => { // export function from module 
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  setToken(null);
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import { removeToken } from './useToken.js' // import removeToken function from useToken.js module
...
<Button variant="danger" onClick={removeToken}>
   LogOut
</Button>
```

*Don't forget to tweak path to the module while importing based on your project structure.*